# Angular UI-Router - empty $stateparams from querystring

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my navigation html on `index.html` I have a search box:

```
<div class="input-group custom-search-form">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.q" placeholder="Search...">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="vm.search()">
            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

In my navigation controller, I handle the button click:

```
function search() {
    $state.go("search", { q: vm.q});
}
```

UI Router has this route:

```
.state("search", {
    url: "/search?:q",
    templateUrl: "/app/search/search.html",
    controller: "search",
    controllerAs: "vm"
})
```

In my `search` controller, this all works fine and I can use this:

```
vm.searchQuery = $stateParams.q;
```

Now, if I open a browser and navigate to `/search?q=test`, then I want the search box to be populated with what is in the query string parameter. I would have thought this was simply a case of changing the navigation controller to the following:

```
vm.q = $stateParams.q;
function search() {
    $state.go("search", { q: vm.searchQuery});
}
```

But `$stateParams` is empty: `{}`.

What's missing/wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use html5Mode you need to append your params after the `/#!/` so probably you need to try this url: `/search/!#/?q=test` to get the `$stateParams` correctly.

Comment: I don't think it's that, because the `state.go` generates the url correctly (using html5Mode) - it's just that the stateParams are not accessible in a different controller, i.e. not the UI route controller.